# Convert SQL SUM CASE WHEN to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sum, case

Need help to convert sql to linq in c#

```
  SELECT    SUM(CASE WHEN Evaluation.StatusId = 3 THEN 1 END)AS EvalutionOK,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Evaluation.StatusId = 4 THEN 1 END) AS EvalutionTodo, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Evaluation.StatusId = 2 THEN 1 END) AS EvalutionNOk
FROM Investor   
INNER JOIN Evaluation ON Evaluation.InvestorId = [dbo].[Investor].Id
```

Sql Result :

EvalutionOK    EvalutionTodo    EvalutionNOk
5                       0                          0

```
List<Investor> Investors = ObjectSet.Include(z =>z.Evaluation).ToList();

var test = from i in Investors 
                       select new TestModel
            { 
                EvalutionTodo = i.Evaluation.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 3? 1 : 0),
                EvalutionOK = i.Evaluation.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 4? 1 : 0),
                EvalutionNOk = i.Evaluation.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 2? 1 : 0),
 };
```

C# result :

Result list  of TestModel

EvalutionOK    EvalutionTodo    EvalutionNOk
1                       0                          0

1                       0                          0

1                       0                          0

1                       0                          0

1                       0                          0

What i am missing? Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: from i in Investors -> you are iterating over any single items.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GroupBy by constant value. It is special case which is handled by LINQ providers.

```cs
var query =
    from i in ObjectSet
    group i.Evaluation by 1 into g
    select new 
    {
        EvalutionOK = g.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 3 ? 1 : 0),
        EvalutionTodo = g.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 4 ? 1 : 0),
        EvalutionNOk = g.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 2 ? 1 : 0)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the single elements, replacing every time the old value.

Try to sum all one time only:

```
var test = new TestModel(){
    EvalutionTodo=0; EvalutionOK =0; EvalutionNOk =0;
} 
Investors.ForEach(i => {
    test.EvalutionTodo += i.Evaluation.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 3? 1 : 0);
    test.EvalutionOK += i.Evaluation.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 4? 1 : 0);
    test.EvalutionNOk += i.Evaluation.Sum(e => e.StatusId == 2? 1 : 0);
});
```